# How to config the aws console for accessing the all instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a .pem file to access an Amazon EC2 instance running Ubuntu and I have 7 instances. I want to create new user and access the all instance in aws console. How can I configure the aws console for accessing all instance with single user?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install the SSH public key for your `.pem` file in the other 6 instances `authorized_keys` file (typically `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`). For that, you need to be able to log into them, of course.

Comment: To clarify, once the instance is created, AWS Console can no longer update SSH keys or any other data on the server.

Comment: create new user and to access the all instance without using .pem , use only the ssh key